# Cannot cast of a division to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code, it prints 0. I need the right result (3.571428571428571) instead.

What is wrong in this code?

```
  declare @result decimal;
  declare @a int; set @a = 56;
  declare @b int; set @b = 2;
  declare @p int; set @p = 100;
  set @result = CAST(((@b / @a)*100) as decimal);
  print @result
```

Comment: covnerting to decimal I get Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called integer division.

> "If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result
>   is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated."

[`/` (Divide) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx)

So use a decimal instead. For example:

```
declare @result decimal(27,17)
declare @a decimal(25,15)
set @a = 56
declare @b decimal(25,15)
set @b = 2

set @result = (@b / @a) * 100
select @result
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18266/0)</kbd>

If you need the result as percent rounded to two decimal places you can use `decimal(5, 2)` and `ROUND`:

```
declare @percent decimal(5,2)
declare @a decimal(25,15)
set @a = 56
declare @b decimal(25,15)
set @b = 2

set @percent = ROUND((@b / @a) * 100, 2)
select @percent
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18273/0)</kbd>

Comment: there is no need to cast decimal to decimal ;) `set @result = (@b / @a)*100` works fine

Comment: in case my @result is a percentage value what is the right precision? example I need from 0,00 to 100,00... is correct decimal(5,2)?

Comment: @WiiMaxx: you can change the scale as you will, for example `decimal(5,2)`. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: sure but this can be done in the declare part of your @result. like you did now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the `cast`, use this:

```
declare @result decimal;
declare @a int; set @a = 56;
declare @b int; set @b = 2;
declare @p int; set @p = 100;
set @result = (cast(@b as decimal) / @a)*100;
print @result
```

It casts the variable `@b` to a `decimal` so the division is done over decimals.

I suggest to convert `a`, `b` and `p` to decimals if possible and cast the end result to an integer if you need to.

Comment: I need result ad decimal with this precision (3.571428571428571), running your code I get result = 4, could you please edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The result of 2/56 is calculated as integer. You have to convert/cast to decimal before dividing.

```
SQL>set ? = 2 / 56;
 ?
==
 0

                  1 row found

SQL>set ? = 2 * 1.0 / 56;
                ?
=================
  0.0357142857142

                  1 row found
```